# Jenkins Simple Theme not applying css

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've a Jenkins instance running on a Centos server through an Nginx proxy. I've installed the Simple Theme plugin, but when I enter a URL in Configure > Theme and save nothing changes. Is there another way to do this?

The theme I'm trying to apply is

```
http://aarjithn.github.io/jenkins-neo-theme/dist/neo-light.css
```

Have also tried other themes fwiw

Comment: are you able to access the css on your browser? Just making sure if its not blocked in your org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by placing the css file on the server itself and adding this to */etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
location /css-theme {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/lib/jenkins/userContent;
    }
```

And

```
https://mydomain/css-theme/jenkins.css
```

in the Simple Theme plugin configuration